# React Native - Android views overlapping on launch

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation

In my App.js I currently have this code in the render function which conditionally renders two stack navigators (React Navigation).

The code works and render fine in iOS.

It also works on Android, but for some reason on both cases it'll show the both views overlapping each other for a fraction of a second.

Does anybody know how can I avoid this overlapping views?

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        isLoadingComplete: false,
        firstLaunch: null,
    };
}

render() {
    if (!this.state.isLoadingComplete) {
        return (
            <AppLoading
                startAsync={this._loadResourcesAsync}
                onError={this._handleLoadingError}
                onFinish={this._handleFinishLoading}
            />
        );
    } else {
        return !this.state.firstLaunch ? <OnboardingStack /> : <MainStack />;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rendering conditionally works fine if you go in following way.

```
    render() {
        if (!this.state.isLoadingComplete) {
           return (
               <AppLoading
                  startAsync={this._loadResourcesAsync}
                  onError={this._handleLoadingError}
                  onFinish={this._handleFinishLoading}
               />
    );
}
return !this.state.firstLaunch ? <OnboardingStack /> : <MainStack />;
return (
 <View>
  <ActivityIndicator />
 </View>
)
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it gives me the same result. It can still see Onboarding (for a fraction of a second) and then MainStack gets rendered on top

Comment: It is checking the if condition in that fraction of second. So until that is happening you can put activityIndicator..like just put return(<View><ActivityIndicator></View>)